# how to do a subtraction after doing a sum with inputs in real time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a sum with some inputs that I have in a form with a series of inputs type checkbox and radio which, when selected, are added together.

But if the user unchecks a checkbox, it does not subtract it, or if he changes the radio button, he does not subtract only addition and addition.

I have this code:

```
    function myFunction() {
    items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemTotalNeto")
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            n = document.getElementById("totalGeneral");
            n.value = parseInt("0"+n.value) + parseInt("0"+this.value);
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
        });
    };

}
```

How can I make it subtract when I uncheck a checkbox and change the radio button?

I'm not a JavaScript expert at all I just started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here is an example (see snippet) that iterates over all the inputs every time any input is changed and sums up all of the checked values. It then replaces the total. No need to subtract if not checked.

```js
const inputArray = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const totalValue = document.querySelector('#totalGeneral');

inputArray.forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener('change', sumValues));

function sumValues() {
  let cboxVals = 0;
  inputArray.forEach(element => cboxVals += element.checked ? parseInt(element.value, 10) : 0);
  totalValue.innerHTML = cboxVals;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 0 5vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}

h3 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: auto;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h3>Sum of selected values: <span id="totalGeneral">0</span></h3>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Select a radio value:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_00" class="itemTotalNeto" name="radioValues" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio_01">0</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_01" class="itemTotalNeto" name="radioValues" value="1">
    <label for="radio_01">1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_02" class="itemTotalNeto" name="radioValues" value="2">
    <label for="radio_02">2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_03" class="itemTotalNeto" name="radioValues" value="3">
    <label for="radio_03">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Select checkbox value(s):</p>
    <input id="chkbox_01" type="checkbox" class="itemTotalNeto" value="1">
    <label for="chkbox_01">1</label>
    <input id="chkbox_02" type="checkbox" class="itemTotalNeto" value="2">
    <label for="chkbox_02">2</label>
    <input id="chkbox_03" type="checkbox" class="itemTotalNeto" value="3">
    <label for="chkbox_03">3</label>
    <input id="chkbox_04" type="checkbox" class="itemTotalNeto" value="4">
    <label for="chkbox_04">4</label>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the checkbox or the radio input is checked or not, after the change event.

```
function myFunction() {
    items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemTotalNeto")
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            n = document.getElementById("totalGeneral");
            //checking here if the checkbox /radio  is checked or not 
            if(this.checked){
                //if checked, add
                n.value = parseInt("0"+n.value) + parseInt("0"+this.value);
            }else{
                //otherwise subtract
                n.value = parseInt("0"+n.value) - parseInt("0"+this.value);
            }


            this.defaultValue = this.value;
        });
    };

}
```